# terminate interactive program from batch

Tags: linux, bash, shell, command-line

I have an interactive program, `cmd`, that I run from batch script. I insert the input as:

```
cmd < $"yes\n3\nn\n"
```

This program `cmd` is a third part software, that I don't intend to modify.

I need to add something at the end of this string in order to terminate the program. The fact is that I have not yet found the clean way to close this program, so far I have been closing it with `Control+C`. How can I insert this at the end of the input string?

Comment: You know that [tag:batch-file] is Windows-related? please reconsider the tags you applied...

Comment: "Yesterday's rose endures in its name, we hold empty names." (cit) No, I didn't know that, I thought it was a synonymous of shell script

Comment: Perhaps you meant [tag:bash]? check out the related [tag info](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/bash/info)...

Comment: Each and every *sane* Unix command taking input from standard input will end when the standard input is closed. From terminal you do that with `^D`, but with redirection it simply happens automatically at the end of the provided input. So you shouldn't need anything at the end. If you do, then it is specific to the command and you'll have to say what particular command you are dealing with.

Comment: I have edited the question. this program is not a standard unix command, but it is a third part software. I would like to know if there is a way to attach `^D` at the end of my input string.

Comment: Unless you provide a link to this mysterious `cmd`, all anyone can do is speculate. What is it and where did you get it? Where is the source? Then we can say with particularity.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that this is indeed bash on linux, I think the following should do what you want:

```
cmd < $'yes\n3\nn\n\cD'
```

Per the [bash hackers wiki](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/quoting#ansi_c_like_strings), in a `$''` string, escape sequences are expanded, and `\cD` is Control-D, or end of file.  As the commenters said, you shouldn't need the explicit control-D for a well-behaved program.  What is `cmd` actually?  Perhaps it manipulates the terminal in fancy ways.  If so, another option might be to use `kill` to manually send `SIGINT` or `SIGHUP` to the process.  Something like:

```
cmd < $'yes\n3\nn\n &
CMD_PID=$!
sleep 10    # or however long "cmd" usually takes
kill -s SIGINT "$CMD_PID"    # or SIGHUP or SIGQUIT instead of SIGINT
```